# Does the D7000 support simultaneous capture of video and stills?

Tags: video, nikon-d7000

Can the Nikon D7000 output video on its HDMI output, with no display overlays, and shoot pictures at the same time, without interruption of the video signal?

Application is using these cameras to capture action, as well as video, which is fed into an HD video mixer, and subsequent mix is recorded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the camera or informed, but my guess is no. The reasoning: this would be an interesting, cool, and unusual video feature, so if it were possible it would be prominent in the marketing materials. (The Canon 5DII, e.g., mentions it - thx @Rowland Shaw.)

(Will delete if someone who is familiar or informed shows up with a more definitive answer.)

Comment: The marketing materials for the Canon 5D mkII states *Users can even shoot video to memory card without losing the ability to capture still images.* I don't know wether you can output an HDMI signal whilst this is happening, I also think that there's a pause in the video whilst the camera is processing the still image... it wouldn't take a breakthrough to enable this, just a little extra processing power / throughput of the image pipeline

Comment: there is a pause of about a second when grabbing a still on the 5D2 - you are also limited on the shooting mode used.

Comment: I'm not smart enough to know if it would be a technical breakthrough (it could be that the sensor can't deliver 30fps at full resolution), but it could still be just an unusual new feature. I'll edit that sentence to try to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the HDMI output is low resolution and has display overlays. You cannot take still images while in video mode, as the camera flips the mirror while taking stills (this would stop the video output for a few seconds).

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI output from the D7000 is not something that can be captured for actual use. It is lower resolution that what you want it for.